# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have a problem with my mysql query, since it returns duplicate values for grouped attributes. For example, for the attribute `q_id` I receive `1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2` instead of `1_-_-_-_-_2` as expected. Two things are confusing.

1. The 1's and 2's get repeated each 8 times. This is probably because there are 8 different `keywords` associated with the `publication`.
2. The repetition of 1's and 2's occurs 2 times. This is due to 2 different `authors` associated with the `publication`.

My query.

```
SELECT 
    sm_publications.id AS p_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(sm_authors.last_name SEPARATOR '_-_-_-_-_') AS a_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(sm_affiliations.display_name SEPARATOR '_-_-_-_-_') AS af_display_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(sm_keywords.name SEPARATOR '_-_-_-_-_') AS k_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(sm_query_publications.query_id SEPARATOR '_-_-_-_-_') AS q_id
FROM sm_publications 
INNER JOIN sm_publication_authors ON sm_publication_authors.publication_id = sm_publications.id
INNER JOIN sm_authors ON sm_authors.id = sm_publication_authors.author_id
LEFT JOIN sm_affiliations ON sm_affiliations.id = sm_authors.affiliation_id
LEFT JOIN sm_publication_keywords ON sm_publication_keywords.publication_id = sm_publications.id
LEFT JOIN sm_keywords ON sm_keywords.id = sm_publication_keywords.keyword_id
INNER JOIN sm_query_publications ON sm_query_publications.publication_id = sm_publications.id 
WHERE sm_publications.id IN (1,2)  /* Just as example */
GROUP BY sm_publications.id
```

The relationships can be seen in the following ERM.
[image]

There are several characteristics.

1. One `publication` has to have `authors`, but `keywords` are not mandatory.
2. One `author` can have an `affiliation`, but it is not mandatory.
3. One `publication` has to refer to one or more `queries`.

**QUESTION**: How can I join all the entities without receiving duplicate attributes? I know, that there is something like `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT [...])`, but it leads to a problem that if there are two `authors` from the same `affiliation`, I only get one `affiliation` back. But in this case, I would like to receive both `affiliations`, although they are the same.

---

An example output looks like.

```
[
{
    "p_id": 1,
    "a_name": 
    "Wang_-_-_-_-_Wang_-_-_-_-_Wang_-_-_-_-_Wang_-_-_-_-_Wang_-_-_-_-_Wang_-_-_-_-_Wang_-_-_-_-_Wang_-_-_-_-_Wang_-_-_-_-_Wang_-_-_-_-_Wang_-_-_-_-_Wang_-_-_-_-_Wang_-_-_-_-_Wang_-_-_-_-_Wang_-_-_-_-_Wang_-_-_-_-_Chen_-_-_-_-_Chen_-_-_-_-_Chen_-_-_-_-_Chen_-_-_-_-_Chen_-_-_-_-_Chen_-_-_-_-_Chen_-_-_-_-_Chen_-_-_-_-_Chen_-_-_-_-_Chen_-_-_-_-_Chen_-_-_-_-_Chen_-_-_-_-_Chen_-_-_-_-_Chen_-_-_-_-_Chen_-_-_-_-_Chen",
    "af_display_name": "North China Electric Power University_-_-_-_-_North China Electric Power University_-_-_-_-_North China Electric Power University_-_-_-_-_North China Electric Power University_-_-_-_-_North China Electric Power University_-_-_-_-_North China Electric Power University_-_-_-_-_North China Electric Power University_-_-_-_-_North China Electric Power University_-_-_-_-_North China Electric Power University_-_-_-_-_North China Electric Power University_-_-_-_-_North China Electric Power University_-_-_-_-_North China Electric Power University_-_-_-_-_North China Electric Power University_-_-_-_-_North China Electric Power University_-_-_-_-_North China Electric Power University_-_-_-_-_North China Electric Power University_-_-_-_-_Huazhong University of Science & Technology_-_-_-_-_Huazhong University of Science & Technology_-_-_-_-_Huazhong University of Science & Technology_-_-_-_-_Huazhong University of Science & Technology_-_-_-_-_Huazhong University of Science & Technology_-_-_-_-_Huazhong University of Scien",
    "k_name": "Genetic Algorithm_-_-_-_-_High Efficiency_-_-_-_-_Improved Genetic Algorithm_-_-_-_-_Rule Extraction_-_-_-_-_Data Mining_-_-_-_-_Explicit Knowledge_-_-_-_-_Artificial Neural Network_-_-_-_-_Neural Network_-_-_-_-_Genetic Algorithm_-_-_-_-_High Efficiency_-_-_-_-_Improved Genetic Algorithm_-_-_-_-_Rule Extraction_-_-_-_-_Data Mining_-_-_-_-_Explicit Knowledge_-_-_-_-_Artificial Neural Network_-_-_-_-_Neural Network_-_-_-_-_Genetic Algorithm_-_-_-_-_High Efficiency_-_-_-_-_Improved Genetic Algorithm_-_-_-_-_Rule Extraction_-_-_-_-_Data Mining_-_-_-_-_Explicit Knowledge_-_-_-_-_Artificial Neural Network_-_-_-_-_Neural Network_-_-_-_-_Genetic Algorithm_-_-_-_-_High Efficiency_-_-_-_-_Improved Genetic Algorithm_-_-_-_-_Rule Extraction_-_-_-_-_Data Mining_-_-_-_-_Explicit Knowledge_-_-_-_-_Artificial Neural Network_-_-_-_-_Neural Network"
    "q_id": "1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2"
}, 
{
    "p_id": 2,
    "a_name": "Mihai_-_-_-_-_Mihai_-_-_-_-_Mihai_-_-_-_-_Mihai_-_-_-_-_Mihai_-_-_-_-_Mihai_-_-_-_-_Mihai_-_-_-_-_Mihai_-_-_-_-_Mihai_-_-_-_-_Mihai_-_-_-_-_Mihai_-_-_-_-_Mihai_-_-_-_-_Mihai_-_-_-_-_Mihai_-_-_-_-_Mihai_-_-_-_-_Mihai",
    "af_display_name": "University of Pitesti_-_-_-_-_University of Pitesti_-_-_-_-_University of Pitesti_-_-_-_-_University of Pitesti_-_-_-_-_University of Pitesti_-_-_-_-_University of Pitesti_-_-_-_-_University of Pitesti_-_-_-_-_University of Pitesti_-_-_-_-_University of Pitesti_-_-_-_-_University of Pitesti_-_-_-_-_University of Pitesti_-_-_-_-_University of Pitesti_-_-_-_-_University of Pitesti_-_-_-_-_University of Pitesti_-_-_-_-_University of Pitesti_-_-_-_-_University of Pitesti",
    "k_name": "Web Content Mining_-_-_-_-_Web Structure Mining_-_-_-_-_Web Mining_-_-_-_-_E Commerce_-_-_-_-_Data Preprocessing_-_-_-_-_Cause Related Marketing_-_-_-_-_Web Usage Mining_-_-_-_-_Data Mining_-_-_-_-_Web Content Mining_-_-_-_-_Web Structure Mining_-_-_-_-_Web Mining_-_-_-_-_E Commerce_-_-_-_-_Data Preprocessing_-_-_-_-_Cause Related Marketing_-_-_-_-_Web Usage Mining_-_-_-_-_Data Mining",
    "q_id": "1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_1_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2_-_-_-_-_2"
}
```

]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could supply a bit of sample data and the table declares it would be possible to test this.

However I think you problem is due to multiple records on each of the joined tables, with the joins then giving you every possible combination which results in duplicates in the GROUP_CONCAT data.

Joining sub queries might work:-

```
SELECT 
    sm_publications.id AS p_id,
    author_inf.a_name,
    affiliations_inf.af_display_name,
    keyword_inf.k_name,
    publications_inf.q_id
FROM sm_publications 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT sm_publication_authors.publication_id, GROUP_CONCAT(sm_authors.last_name SEPARATOR '_-_-_-_-_') AS a_name
    FROM sm_publication_authors 
    INNER JOIN sm_authors ON sm_authors.id = sm_publication_authors.author_id
    GROUP BY sm_publication_authors.publication_id
) author_inf
ON author_inf.publication_id = sm_publications.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT sm_publication_authors.publication_id, GROUP_CONCAT(sm_affiliations.display_name SEPARATOR '_-_-_-_-_') AS af_display_name
    FROM sm_publication_authors 
    INNER JOIN sm_authors ON sm_authors.id = sm_publication_authors.author_id
    LEFT JOIN sm_affiliations ON sm_affiliations.id = sm_authors.affiliation_id
    GROUP BY sm_affiliations.publication_id
) affiliations_inf
ON affiliations_inf.publication_id = sm_publications.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT sm_publication_keywords.publication_id, GROUP_CONCAT(sm_keywords.name SEPARATOR '_-_-_-_-_') AS k_name
    FROM sm_publication_keywords 
    LEFT JOIN sm_keywords ON sm_keywords.id = sm_publication_keywords.keyword_id
    GROUP BY sm_publication_keywords.publication_id
) keyword_inf
ON keyword_inf.publication_id = sm_publications.id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT sm_query_publications.publication_id, GROUP_CONCAT(sm_query_publications.query_id SEPARATOR '_-_-_-_-_') AS q_id
    FROM sm_query_publications
    GROUP BY sm_query_publications.publication_id
) publications_inf
ON publications_inf.publication_id = sm_publications.id
WHERE sm_publications.id IN (1,2)  /* Just as example */
```

Comment: I have actually thought about subqueries - but how does the performance looks like? So as far as I can see, I can either use subqueries and have to fear bad performance or I have to split the queries, such that the results do not get multiplied.

Comment: Performance is possibly an issue (although it would depends on indexes, etc). Splitting the queries would probably give even worse performance as you would still be doing the same sub queries just adding the overhead of multiple calls to the database. The only other way I can think to do it would be using CONCAT to group up the sub fields before using GROUP_CONCAT to concatenate the data. But this would then leave you having to split the data back up again in the calling script.

Comment: By splitting the queries I meant that I would select the publication's data in such a manner, that I would end up having three queries. All the queries would access the publication table, but per query I would only select one n:m-entity (authors or keywords, or queries). But the second approach you mentioned looks also interesting. I will defininatelly try it out and since I now know what the problems are, I can accept you answer.